# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have this code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(indir="D:\\python\\in", outfile="D:\\python\\out\\Concatenated1.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=["produs","pret","descriere","luna"]
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename), 
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename, header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
```

I receive this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM: are you sure? The error tell us that it is not UTF-8 (sig = bom, which it is a valid unicode character). For Cristina: Use `encoding='cp1252'`, and then according the wrong characters, you may refine the encoding

Comment: Thank you both so much. I used `pandas.read_csv(filename,header=None, encoding='utf-8')    `  And it worked.